# Capybara::ElementNotFound and ArgumentError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I updated Rspec and now half of my Rspec tests are failing.

Originally, all tests were failing, and I was able to get half of them to pass by adding "config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!" to spec_helper.rb.

The first type of error message is an Argument Error:

```
  1) todo_lists/new renders new todo_list form
 Failure/Error: assigns(:todo_list, stub_model(TodoList,
 ArgumentError:
   wrong number of arguments (2 for 0..1)
 # ./spec/views/todo_lists/new.html.erb_spec.rb:5:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

The second type is Capybara::ElementNotFound:

```
  5) Editing Todo Lists displays error when description is empty
 Failure/Error: fill_in "Title", with: options[:title]
 Capybara::ElementNotFound:
   Unable to find field "Title"
 # ./spec/features/todo_lists/edit_spec.rb:18:in `update_todo_lists'
 # ./spec/features/todo_lists/edit_spec.rb:55:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

My Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.1.4'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc

gem 'spring',        group: :development

group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
end


group :test do
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'shoulda-matchers'
end

gem 'rspec-activemodel-mocks'
```

Spec_Helper File:

```
   ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
# require 'rspec/autorun'
require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'capybara/rails'

Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each { |f| require f }


ActiveRecord::Migration.check_pending! if defined?(ActiveRecord::Migration)

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include TodoListHelpers, type: :feature
  config.include Capybara::DSL

  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

  config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false
  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!

  config.order = "random"
end

module ::RSpec::Core
  class ExampleGroup
    include Capybara::DSL
    include Capybara::RSpecMatchers
  end
end
```

todo_lists/new.html.erb_spec :

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "todo_lists/new" do
  before(:each) do
    assigns(:todo_list, stub_model(TodoList,
      :title => "MyString",
      :description => "MyText"
    ).as_new_record)
  end

  it "renders new todo_list form" do
    render

# Run the generator again with the --webrat flag if you want to use webrat matchers
assert_select "form[action=?][method=?]", todo_lists_path, "post" do
  assert_select "input#todo_list_title[name=?]", "todo_list[title]"
  assert_select "textarea#todo_list_description[name=?]", "todo_list[description]"


  end
  end
end
```

features/todo_lists/edit_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Editing Todo Lists" do
  let!(:todo_list) {TodoList.create(title:       "Groceries",
                                    description: "Grocery list")}

  def update_todo_lists(options={})
    options[:title] ||= "New Title"
    options[:description] ||= "New Description"

todo_list = options[:todo_list]

visit '/todo_lists'
within "#todo_list_#{todo_list.id}" do
  click_link "Edit"
end

fill_in "Title", with: options[:title]
fill_in "Description", with: options[:description]
click_button "Update Todo list"
  end

  it "displays error when description is empty" do
update_todo_lists todo_list: todo_list, description: ""
description = todo_list.description

todo_list.reload

expect(page).to have_content("error")
expect(todo_list.description).to eq(description)


end
```

The edit view:

```
<h1>Editing todo_list</h1>
```

|

and the form helper:

```
<%= form_for(@todo_list) do |f| %>
  <% if @todo_list.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@todo_list.errors.count, "error") %> 

`prohibited this todo_list from being saved:</h2>`

  <ul>
  <% @todo_list.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
    <li><%= message %></li>
  <% end %>
  </ul>
</div>
```

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">


   <%= f.label :description %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :description %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Try launching a Capybara session in irb and replicate what is in your test file. If you encounter a problem it will be easier to debug. It sounds like the only changes you made were updating your Gemfile, but doesn't hurt to conduct a sanity test on the second spec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your view file you've a text_field as `:title` but in spec file you're filling Title.
Which can not be accessed by the Capybara. So that's why Capybara is not finding Title.

Other solution could be Try inspecting your title in console. What is the id for title.

If the id is something like "todo_title" then you should keep the same in the spec file.

Like this `fill_in "todo_title"` instead of `fill_in "Title"`

You can solve this problem with any of the above solutions. It worked for me.

You can also refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27227328/capybaraelementnotfound-unable-to-find-field-title).