# Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find field "title"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I  could not resolve this issue. Please help me. It gives me element not found error.

spec/features/todos/create_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Creating todos" do

 let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user)}
 before(:each) do
   visit root_path
   click_link "Login"

   fill_in "Email",  with:  "user@gmail.com"
   fill_in "Password",  with: "password"
   click_button "Sign in"
 end

  it "redirects to the todos index page" do
   visit "/todos"

   fill_in "title", with: "MyString"
   click_button "Create"

   expect(page).to have_title("MyString")
 end
```

my view code.
_new_form.html.erb

```
     <%= form_for current_user.todos.new, remote:true  do |f| %>
       <div class="input-group">
         <%= f.text_field :title, class: "form-control",   placeholder: "title" %>
         <span class="input-group-btn">
         <%= f.submit "Create", class: "btn btn-success" %>
         </span>
       </div>
     <% end %>
```

spec_helper.rb

```
    def sign_in
      @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
      controller.stub(:authenticate_user!).and_return(true)
      @user
    end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found my answer.

In the view file I've a text_field with title with an id.  The id = todo_title in the console
But am calling title in the test . Here the capybara not been able to find title. It was todo_title

After using

```
fill_in "todo_title"
```

It worked like charm.

Answer (score 6):

If you have the code running on a server locally, inspect the element and the name of the field is what Capybara needs to run. Generally, if the form is nested, the name rails will come up with (in this case) is something like `todos[title]`.

So, spec/features/todos/create_spec.rb should look something like:

```
require 'spec_helper'
 ...

it "redirects to the todos index page" do
 visit "/todos"

 fill_in "todos[title]", with: "MyString"
 click_button "Create"

 expect(page).to have_title("MyString")
end
```

Answer (score 1):

In your form, there must be an element with the name as "title". From the [docs](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara/Node/Actions:fill_in):

```
fill_in(locator, options = {}) ⇒ Object

Locate a text field or text area and fill it in with the given text The field can be found via its name, id or label text.
```